# Obstruction to be conjugated by an automorphism for subgroups of an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finite abelian p-group( p being a prime number). Let $M,N$ be subgroup such that $M \simeq N$ and $A/M \simeq A/N$ as groups. Can I conclude that there is $\phi \in Aut(A)$ such that $\phi(M)=N$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221629/obstruction-for-two-subgroups-to-be-conjugated-by-an-automorphism?noredirect=1#comment546788_221629 Here is a counterexample of Derek Holt on mathoverflow